# angular create cross origin http request

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular-http

I have an old `android` application that I'm looking to refactor into `ìonic2` to create a cross platform application.

in the android app, i use `Jsoup` with the following call `Jsoup.connect(url).get();`

This works with no issues and I am returned a html page that I can parse.
However, if I try this with ionic2 (angular2) using the following

```
loadTimetableData(url) {
let headers = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/form-url-encoded;',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
});
return this._http.get(url, { headers: headers }).map((res) => res).catch(this._errorHandler);
}
```

I get the standard CORS error `(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load ${URL}. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.`

It's not my server so I cannot add the header server side. Is there an alternative library that I can use, or how can I get around this, if at all

Comment: This is unfortunately a server side problem and absolutely nothing you can do to fix it from the browser. The only hack I can think of is to use a proxy that will inject the missing headers.

Answer (score 0):

you can try changing the header type as i am using this headers in GET method

and note you just added `;` in

```
'Content-Type': 'application/form-url-encoded;',
```

which is not needed and could cause error

try to change it to .

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
```

complete code

```
loadTimetableData(url) {
let headers = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
});
return this._http.get(url, { headers: headers }).map((res) => res).catch(this._errorHandler);
}
```